# How do I disable SVN for a folder in my repository?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, repository

I have a folder that holds all my project files. It's is for a video game, so there are lots of graphics files. How do I disable SVN for the folder(s) in Tortoise SVN since I have limited storage space? Thanks.

Comment: Question is unclear: If you dont't want to add the files, then don't add the files before you commit.  If they are already committed, and you want to remove them, then svn delete them..  if you want to remove them from the previous commits that added then and continued to contain them, that's a bit more complicated.

Comment: Read the documentation https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

Answer (score 2):

The comment that says the question is unclear actually doesn't seem to understand it's use case and the question is very clear at least to me. There is no need to delete anything or overcomplicate things.

You should have a look at the depths in the svn guide. I've found out now that it's called a [Sparce checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.sparsedirs), so I've learnt something new, too.

This checkout command will only get any of its immediate file or directory children. The directory children will themselves be empty:

```
svn checkout file:///var/svn/repos mom-empty --depth immediates
```

This way you can set the depths for the different directories in your svn tree, so when you update, they won't get all the game assets but just the folders with the code.

If you already have a checkedout folder, you can also change the depth by:

`svn up --set-depth immediates`

A similar question is found in here [svn-checkout-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650156/svn-checkout-depth).

I was wondering for what OS you might be asking but now I saw the tortoise-svn tag. [You can change the checkout depth from its GUI, like it is shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoE7w.jpg)